# i want to embed iframe table from website

Tags: html, iframe, embed, embedded-resource

I want to embed the currency rate table from this website https://myfin.by/currency/russia
without embedding the whole page!
so anyone can type the right embedding code for me!
thank you >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution but you can get the ID of the table `#currency-content`, add this onto the URL to go to that part of the page. https://myfin.by/currency/russia#currency-content

I then made the iframe have scrolling off so that you can't see the rest of the site. You probably want to add a `width` as well because it is currently very thin.

```html
<iframe scrolling='no' height="3200" src="https://myfin.by/currency/russia#currency-content"></iframe>
```